# ¿Cómo puedo agregar la marca de tiempo a un archivo?

Tags: python, datetime, concatenación

¿Cómo puedo concatenar en *Python* el valor de `fecha` al nombre de un archivo `archivo=fecha+.log` para que me quede con el formato `2018-10-29-12:31:31.log`?

Código:

```
from datetime import datetime
fecha=datetime.now()
```

Comment: sigo con mi duda de como concatenar el valor de una variable con el nombre de otra variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable `fecha` es un objeto de tipo `datetime`. Tienes que obtener su representación como cadena para poder usarlo como nombre de fichero o poder concatenarle cosas.

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto. Por ejemplo, tomando tu modelo podría ser:

```
filename = str(fecha) + ".log"
```

Pero también usando cadenas de formato, por ejemplo:

```
filename = "{}.log".format(fecha)
```

En este caso no necesistas pasar la fecha a `str` porque la propia función `format` lo hace cuando no especificas el tipo de lo que va entre llaves.

Eso te dará la representación por defecto de la fecha, que tiene el aspecto:

```
2018-10-29 11:58:26.251760
```

Para tener control más preciso sobre la forma en que quieres que se convierta, puedes usar `strftime()`. En tu caso, si no me equivoco, no quieres mostrar las fracciones de segundo, y quieres que la hora vaya unida a la fecha por un guión. Entonces esta sería la [cadena de formato](http://strftime.org/) a uar:

```
filename = "{}.log".format(fecha.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"))
print(filename)
```

```
2018-10-29-11:58:26.log
```

Una vez tienes creado el nombre de fichero en la variable `filename`, puedes usarlo para crear el fichero, por ejemplo así:

```
with open(filename, "w") as f:
   f.write("Probando..\n")
```

Eso creará un fichero llamado `2018-10-29-11:58:26.log`

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85043/discussion-on-answer-by-abulafia-como-puedo-agregar-la-marca-de-tiempo-un-archiv).